# How to go Auto start permission page in Honor 10 Lite?

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, autostart, huawei-developers

In my app, i want to enable auto start when user is logging into app. So i am using like below

```
val powerManagerIntent = arrayOf(

Intent().setComponent(
    ComponentName(
        "com.huawei.systemmanager",
        "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity"
    )
),
Intent().setComponent(
    ComponentName(
        "com.huawei.systemmanager",
        "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"
    )
),
Intent().setComponent(
    ComponentName(
        "com.huawei.systemmanager",
        "com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity"
    )
)
)
```

And

```
 for (intent in Utils.powerManagerIntent) if (packageManager.resolveActivity(
                intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
            ) != null
        ) {
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(
this@StartChildModeActivity,
R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
.setTitle("Enable AutoStart")
.setMessage("Please allow AppName to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed.")
.setCancelable(false)
.setNegativeButton(resources.getString(R.string.btn_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
    dialog.dismiss()
}
.setPositiveButton("ALLOW") { dialog, _ ->
}.show()
}
```

Huawei device is working fine and honor is crashing when trying this. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: hi, may i ask what is your test device and EMUI version?

Comment: It's EMUI 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below 2 intent components:

```
val powerManagerIntent = arrayOf(
    Intent().setComponent(
        ComponentName(
            "com.huawei.systemmanager",
            "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"
        )
    ),
    Intent().setComponent(
        ComponentName(
            "com.huawei.systemmanager",
            "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity"
        )
    ),
    )
```

Also, please try to add the below permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>
```

Comment: It moves to internal storage (File Explorer)

Comment: hi@The Bala, To solve your problem, 1. Please provide the code 2. Provide the screen recording of the issue. 3. Device details, EMUI version, Android Version(screenshots if possible) 4. Attach the log. The procedure for capturing logs is as follows:
1. Run the following command to connect to the device:
    adb logcat –v time > D:\hwlog.log
2. Reproduce the fault.
3. Press Ctrl+C to complete log capture.

Comment: hi, this intents not work anymore? emui 12.0.0.228